# I need to know ARM Trustzone Usecases

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, zynq, trustzone

I am currently understanding ARM trustzone technology. Can anybody please suggest some basic use cases of Trust Zone for prototype development on Zynq board.

Comment: "Running some verified code that the user cannot interfere with" pretty much sums up every use case - there are innumerable reasons why you might want to be able to do that, both at the firmware level and the application level. Have you come across the [TrustZone whitepaper](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.prd29-genc-009492c/index.html) yet?

Answer (score 2):

Before looking at useful use cases you should start with a good old ["Hello, world!" example](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15417.html).

This example is also targetting the *Cortex-A9*, which is fine for you and your *Zedboard*. The sad news are: this example from ARM is designed to be used with *RVDS 4.1 Professional SP1* toolchain. So if you are cross-compiling with the *GNU toolchain*, you will need to do some adaptations (probably not much) to compile and link the code. The guy here has already made it [compile and run a bit](http://community.arm.com/message/3935). This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688559/running-arm-trustzone-secure-normal-worldexample-on-the-zedboard) could also help.

By the way, Zynq offers a very interesting manual on this topic, do you missed it? Anyway, it's [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug1019-zynq-trustzone.pdf).

To go further with *TrustZone* head to this very complete and interesting article: [An Exploration of ARM TrustZone Technology](http://genode.org/documentation/articles/trustzone)